# Java Array Crash

Tags: java, arrays

```
public static ItemStack[] OreMelterAccept;
private static int arraySlot = 0;

public static addOreMelterRecipe(ItemStack itemStack) {
OreMelterAccept[arraySlot] = itemStack;
arraySlot++;
 }
```

Compiler says that the code is ok but everytime I try to execute it... it gives me an error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You don't initialize your `ItemStack[]` array. Might I suggest something like this: `ItemStack[] OreMelterAccept = new ItemStack[63];`

Comment: What exactly is the exception/stack trace? Are you initializing the array anywhere?

Comment: Thats all the code related to that array

Comment: @Sam _it gives me an error_ It would be helpful to share that with us.

Comment: Like @Trobbins said, you need to initialize the array. If that's all the code, then you need to google "initialize java array". There should be an exception that it tells you when it crashes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200621/declare-array-in-java

Answer (score 1):

You never initialized your array. You must explicitly initialize the array like so:

```
public static ItemStack[] OreMelterAccept = new ItemStack[10];//10 is just an example
```

Comment: The comments were getting a little out of hand here, so I purged them. If you want to continue the discussion about voting behavior, I recommend taking that to chat or to Meta.